# Is it possible to put half of a while loop in between one php tags and another half in another php tags like I show in there?

Tags: php

Is this possible to do? For example the bracket that close the while is in different php tags of the ones that start the while loop.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $code = $row["VAT"];
?>
<option name="Client VAT" value="<?php echo($code); ?>"><?php echo $code; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word  - yes. PHP will continue the parsing of the PHP code in the next `<?php` tag without an issue.

Comment: I am having a strange problem. In my computer the website works but when I am uploading the files to my university servers the website online shows up to that piece of code. I thought that could be that piece of code, but for what I see it is not. Thanks for the answer